# Persist/commit not working in test environment with Spring JPA JUnit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

I'm trying to setup a basic JPA insert test. But nothing is saved in the DB.
DB is Postgresql. Hibernate is used as Persistence provider.

Many thanks in advance.

```
@Entity
public class Currency {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;    

    @Column
    private String code;

    @Column
    private String name;
...
}
```

The CRUD class :

```
@Repository
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class CRUDServiceBean implements CRUDService {

      @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
      private EntityManager entityManager;

       public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return entityManager;
        }

        public <T extends BaseEntity> T persistAndCommit(T t) {
            entityManager.persist(t);
            entityManager.refresh(t);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            return t;
        }

        ...
        ...
}
```

Base class for all tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context-test.xml" })
public class BaseTest {
}
```

The test class:

```
public class CurrencyCreateTest extends BaseTest {

    @Autowired
    CRUDService crudService;

    @Test
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createCurrency() throws Exception {
        Currency currency = new Currency();
        currency.setCode("EUR");
        currency.setName("Euro");
        currency = crudService.persistAndCommit(currency);
    }
}
```

context-test.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">         

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.chartinvest"/>

    <bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider" class="com.chartinvest.util.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean> 


    <!-- the parent application context definition for the springapp application -->

    <!-- dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSourceFinance" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName"><value>org.postgresql.Driver</value></property>
      <property name="url"><value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db_finance_test</value></property>
      <property name="username"><value>postgres</value></property>
      <property name="password"><value>xxxxxxxx</value></property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />       
    </bean>  

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mypersistenceunit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceFinance" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->       
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Try to add `entityManager.merge(t)` before your `entityManager.persist(t)` in your `persistAndCommit`

Comment: What does it mean it's not working? Do you get an error? Or do you expect some result and it is different? Please share the expected vs. actual behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your test passed successfully and you do not get any exception so use **@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)** per test class or use **@Rollback(false)** per test method.
Transactional tests will rollback by default in spring test context.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={
  "test-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
public class SampleCrudTest {

    @Autowired
    private SampleCrud sampleCrud;

    @Before 
    public void onSetUpInTransaction() throws Exception {
        //Populate Test Data
    }


    @Test
    public void registerSample() {

        Sample sample = new Sample("foo");
        sampleCrud.save(sample);
        assertNotNull(sample.getId());
    }

}
```

Comment: I added  @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)  on the test class and now I see a new entry in the table CURRENCY.  Many thanks for help !!!

Comment: Please. You can choose my answer as right answer it helps others to solve problems.

Comment: @Deprecated now. Use 
`@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)`
`@Rollback(false)`

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the following in the log file:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute getTransaction() on a container-managed EntityManager
    at 
...
...
```

So, I removed

> entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

from the method persistAndCommit(T) in CRUDServiceBean

This removed the exception, and there are no other exceptions anymore.
The output of the test shows the following:

```
Hibernate: insert into Currency (code, name) values (?, ?)
```

However, no record has been written in the table CURRENCY.

It's like after the test finishes, Hibernate removes the inserted record.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the test (or the test base class) with `@Rollback(false)`

e.g:

```
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Rollback(false)
abstract class RepositoryTest {
  ...
}

class UserReportitoryTest extends RepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

   @Test
   void it_should_save_the_user() {
     repository.save(user);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me, Ensure you initiate the transaction and commit the transaction.

```
public Transaction startTransaction(Session session) throws HibernateException {
        return session.beginTransaction();
    }

...... your test code goes here......

public void endTransaction(Session session) throws HibernateException {

        if (session != null) {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
```